# If we forward a Email style="display: none" property deleted or vanish

Tags: css, layout, html-email

Almost all email service provider support style="display: none" property but when we forward the mail from Outlook (windows) and view in gmail style="display: none" property deleted or vanish. How can I retain display property in Email?

Comment: Where is the `display:none` - inline, or in the `<head>` section? If it is in the head, Outlook will strip it on forwarding. But you might have better luck if it is inline.

Comment: Thanks. I have added display:none - inline. After receiving mail it is supporting display: none property almost all ESP. But when I forward same mail from Outlook Windows or Mac and view in Gmail G-suite it remove property of display:none from element.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the behavior of a email client, you have to deal with it. For example `style="display: none"` is not supported at all on Gmail mobile webmail.

[caniemail](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display-none/) may help you to find workarounds and alternatives.

Comment: That's when looking at Gmail on your phone on the browser, not the apps - which do support it. I suspect it's because Outlook is stripping the `<head>` section on forwarding